# References for Pocket PC

Tags: pocketpc, smart-device

Iam going to develop a Pocket PC application. Actually I dont have enough knowledge about programming in Pocket PC's. Can anyone suggest me some references( Basics and Advanced) which will be helpful for me in developing that Pocket PC application.

Comment: Did you mean Windows Mobile? Because for all intents and purposes, Pocket PC is dead.

Comment: @mvp, not Windows Mobile. I need to work on Pocket PC. Because it is still useful for some tasks. Thats why I need it....Can u help in it ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need Visual Studio Professional 2003-2008, and 2008 is preferred.

It is getting difficult to find Visual Studio 2008 Professional, though. Dare I say: You may have to resort to pirating it off a torrent site.

After 2008, Microsoft stopped supporting PocketPC and Windows Mobile in Visual Studio.

You can not use the Express versions of Visual Studio, because they have no way to create a Device Project.

You could even go older and get [eMbedded VC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16683), but it may only work on Windows XP machines, not Vista or Win7. Be warned: VS2008 is so much faster to create your apps with.

Comment: Thankx for ur reply @jp2code, also I need some references to work on it. Can u suggest me...?